# atan2 for two sinusoids of arbitrary phase shift?

Tags: c, algorithm, math, atan2

I'm trying to implement an atan2-like function to map two input sinusoidal signals of arbitrary relative phase shift to a single output signal that linearly goes from `0` to `2π`.  `atan2` normally assumes two signals with a 90 deg phase shift.

#### Given `y0(x) = sin(x)` and `y1 = sin(x + phase)`, where `phase` is a fixed non-zero value, how can I implement a way to return `x` modulo `2π`?

Comment: Is this a correct restatement of the problem: Given y0 and y1 that are sin(x) and sin(x+phase), where phase is a constant, return x modulo 2π?

Comment: Please restate exactly the problem as it is not clear. atan2(y,x) works on an y and an x and calculates the angle of the line passing from (0,0) and (x,y) with respect to the positive axis of x giving a result from -π excluded to +π included.

Comment: Note: `-π <= atan2() <= +π`, not the same range as [0...2π), nor `fmod(a, 2*M_PI)`.

Comment: This seems like a math question more than a programming question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`atan2` returns the angle of a 2d vector. Your code does not handle such scaling properly. But no worries, it's actually very easy to reduce your problem to an `atan2` that would handle everything nicely.

Notice that calculating `sin(x)` and `sin(x + phase)` is the same as projecting a point `(cos(x), sin(x))` onto the axes `(0, 1)` and `(sin(phase), cos(phase))`. This is the same as taking dot products with those axes, or transforming the coordinate system from the standard orthogonal basis into the skewed one. This suggests a simple solution: inverse the transformation to get the coordinates in the orthogonal basis and then use `atan2`.

Here's a code that does that:

```
double super_atan2(double x0, double x1, double a0, double a1) {
    double det = sin(a0 - a1);
    double u = (x1*sin(a0) - x0*sin(a1))/det;
    double v = (x0*cos(a1) - x1*cos(a0))/det;
    return atan2(v, u);
}

double duper_atan2(double y0, double y1, double phase) {
    const double tau = 6.28318530717958647692; // https://tauday.com/
    return super_atan2(y0, y1, tau/4, tau/4 - phase);
}
```

`super_atan2` gets the angles of the two projection axes, `duper_atan2` solves the problem exactly as you stated.

Also notice that the calculation of `det` is not strictly necessary. It is possible to replace it by `fmod` and `copysign` (we still need the correct sign of `u` and `v`).

Answer (score 1):

**Derivation:**

[image: derivation]

**In code:**

```
// assume phase != k * pi, for any integer k
double f (double y0, double y1, double phase)
{
    double u = (- y0 * cos(phase) + y1) / sin(phase);
    double v = y0;

    double x = atan2 (v, u);
    return (x < 0) ? (x + 2 * M_PI) : x;
}
```